# extract IP and port from string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have string

```
Timestamp: 1594312360   Host: 127.0.0.1 ()        Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh//
Timestamp: 1412355121   Host: 127.0.0.1 ()  Ports: 21/open/tcp//telnet//
Timestamp: 1594741231  Host: 127.0.0.1 ()        Ports: 8080/open/tcp//http//
Timestamp: 1232370123   Host: 127.0.0.1 ()  Ports: 443/open/tcp//https//
```

and i would like a with just the ip:Port

```
127.0.0.1:22
127.0.0.1:21
127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1:443
```

can anyone help me do this i am using Vb.net
if use Regex no problem

Comment: You could find the [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1) "Host: " and " (" and get the [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1) between, and similarly for the port number.

Comment: It's not for us to write your code for you or teach you from scratch. If you've made no effort so far then it's too soon to be posting here. You should not have rejected the prompt to take the site tour when you registered or you'd have a better idea of what is expected of questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it on space (your data appears to contain spaces rather than tabs), with the RemoveEmptyEntries option set:

```
For Each line in File.ReadLines("c:\temp\mylog.txt")

  'line is eg "Timestamp: 1594312360   Host: 127.0.0.1 ()        Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh//"
  Dim array = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Next line
```

Array now contains:

```
(0): Timestamp:
(1): 1594312360
(2): Host:
(3): 127.0.0.1 
(4): ()
(5): Ports: 
(6): 22/open/tcp//ssh//
```

You can reach the IP using the third index and the port via the 6th, or last (which you choose depends on what your data contains on other lines we can't see)

You'll have to discard everthing after the first index of '/' in the ports line:

```
Dim port = array(6).Remove(array(6).IndexOf("/"c))
```

---

If you want to use regex (which you should indicate in your question; by just asking open ended "how can i?" it doesn't impose any constraint as to how..) you can look at something like:

```
Dim r = new Regex("Host: (?<ip>[0-9.]+).*?Ports: (?<p>\d+)")

Dim m = r.Match(line)

Console.WriteLine(m.Groups("ip").Value)
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups("p").Value)
```

The regex means

> `Host: (?<ip>[0-9.]+).*?Ports: (?<p>\d+)`

Find `Host:` , followed by multiple digits or periods and capture them into a group named ip, followed by any number of anything until the word `Ports:` , followed by any number of digits captured into a group named p

Comment: I do, I'm not sure I'd use it for this, but I can add something